# Having Issues getting custom posts by Advanced Custom Fields (meta_key and meta_value)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I don't know why I am having this issues, I've done this sort of thing before, hopefully somebody can help shed some light on this situation.

```
$arch_state = get_field('service_area_archive_state');

$args01 = array(
        'post_type'         => 'service-area',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'title',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_key'          => 'service_area_state',
        'meta_value'        => $arch_state
    );

    $serv_areas = get_posts($args01);
```

then, I use a foreach loop to go through the query.

```
foreach($serv_areas as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);

    ...

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

for some reason, this query isn't returning anything. I am able to get the all the posts of that custom post type without an issue when I remove the meta_key and meta_value fields.

But for some reason, as soon as I add the meta key and meta value, nothing...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to put two quotations '' between $arch_state so its like this:

```
$args01 = array(
        'post_type'         => 'service-area',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'title',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_key'          => 'service_area_state',
        'meta_value'        => '.$arch_state.'
    );
```

Try to set value there and see if its working 'meta_value' 
more you can see here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/